# Text background color in RichTextFx CodeArea

Tags: javafx, richtextfx

I'm using RichTextFx (CodeArea) to highlight my code. I want to change text background color for some keywords and use css below:

```
.parameter {
    -rtfx-background-color: yellow;
}
```

But it's changes background color for all text between my keywords (`:p1` and `:p2` in this example). Font color and style change successfully.
[image]

Comment: This is what i was searching for ` -rtfx-background-color: yellow;` Thank you so much!

Comment: You have to use something like `textArea.setStyle(from,to, "style");` where textArea is a RichTextFx (CodeArea) . For me it works like charm!

Answer (score 1):

use `StyleClassedTextArea.setStyleClass(from, to, "class Name");` to add class name to some specific range.