# RichTextFX: Highlighting a Word in StyleClassedTextArea not working

Tags: java, css, user-interface, javafx, richtextfx

I am new to RichTextFX and need some help. I want to use StyleClassedTextArea (see https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX).

My simple java code:

```
public class GuiMain extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        
        StyleClassedTextArea styleClassedTextArea = new StyleClassedTextArea();
        String exampleString = "This is a WARNING for an INFO! Please stay tuned";
        styleClassedTextArea.appendText(exampleString);
        styleClassedTextArea.setStyle(10, 16, Collections.singleton("-fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-highlight-fill: #B22224;"));
        styleClassedTextArea.setEditable(false);

        Scene scene2 = new Scene(new StackPane(styleClassedTextArea), 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene2);
        primaryStage.setTitle("");
        primaryStage.setMaximized(false);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

But when I run my java program, I just get the following:
[image]

However, as the picture shows, nothing is highlighted.
Does anyone know how I can render the text in a certain range (from, to) in red (or what I have done wrong)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all of you who are facing the same problem:

Instead of -fx-highlight-fill, you can use RichTextFX with -rtfx-background-color: #...

Solution found here: [Text background color in RichTextFx CodeArea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47111153/text-background-color-in-richtextfx-codearea)